# Grunt task to precompile Hamlbars (HAML with handlebars expressions)

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, handlebars.js, grunt-contrib-haml

There's [grunt-contrib-handlebars](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-handlebars) and grunt-[grunt-contrib-haml](https://gemnasium.com/npms/grunt-contrib-haml), but I need the combination of the two. Say I have a "hamlbars" template like the following:

```
%div
  {{ name }}
```

I need this to be precompiled into JavaScript just as `grunt-contrib-handlebars` would do to

```
<div>
  {{ name }}
</div>
```

There's also [grunt-hamlbars](https://github.com/hrysd/grunt-hamlbars) but I could not get it to work. It however only compiles hamlbars to handlebars, I need to take a step further and precompile the handlebars.

Perhaps I'm taking the wrong approach? Should I just stick with normal HTML and handlebars? Is there a seamless way to compile HAML into HTML then precompile as a handlebars file, all using Grunt?

Comment: You could pre compile the Handlebars and then take that output and compile the HAML. However since there is already a Grunt task for HamlBars I would recommend using that. Can you post a link to your Grunt file so we can try and figure out why grunt-hamlbars is not working?

Comment: @NoahHuppert how could I precompile Handlebars _then_ compile the HAML? The precompilation will result in JavaScript which Ruby cannot interpret

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. If you are using Handlebars then the `{{foo}}` should be replaced with `foo`(Or whatever value). So then when you compile the Haml the `{{}}` will be gone.

Comment: @NoahHuppert No, I'm referring to _precompilation_, not runtime compilation. Precompiling means the markup and everything is already converted to a big JavaScript function which can be directly executed at runtime, passing `foo` into that function. Like so: http://handlebarsjs.com/precompilation.html

Comment: I'm having the same issue.

Would it not be possible to use the HAML api to compile the HAML first to HTML, and then doing the precompilation task as usual?